# unable to view my IIS hosted site from remote machine but IIS page open

Tags: asp.net, iis

The IP of the machine is suppose `104.68.125.105`

In this machine, I configured the IIS server and successfully opened my web app http://merchantcalc/content/lateFine.aspx from inside this machine. This app has default port i.e. 80

But when I tried to open the same web app from remote computer, via url 
http://104.68.125.105/merchantcalc/content/lateFine.aspx

I am getting error as ::

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
The resource cannot be found.
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
```

when I open 
`http://103.69.125.101/` from remote machine, its showing the `IIS` page.

But why can't I open the web apps? What configuration should I make in IIS to open my web app ?

Comment: You need to use http://104.68.125.105/content/lateFine.aspx

Answer (score 0):

As Mark said, if you can access http://merchantcalc/content/lateFine.aspx, then you should try http://103.xx.xxx.xxx/content/lateFine.aspx.

Did you host the web site under another website or you just publish the web app as a virtual application under your Default web site? It seems that when you access the website, http.sys is routing the request to Default Web Site. So if this is not the right site that should be routed. You could try to disable Default Web Site and bind your ip address to your web app.

Since there are various kinds of 404 error. You could check the sub-status code by enabling IIS detailed error or failed request tracing.

PS: Expose your public IP address is not recommended.

If you could provide more information, we may get to know how to fix this 404 error.